# How to add search result to textbox when clicked in (like Multi-select boxes (pillbox))

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have been stuck with this , when i click the first button then the second button i need the value to be appended with each other not overwritten .

you can find below the image link .
thank you

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $('.search-box input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function(){
        /* Get input value on change */
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
        if(inputVal.length){
            $.get("backend-search.php", {term: inputVal}).done(function(data){
                // Display the returned data in browser
                resultDropdown.html(data);
            });
        } else{
            resultDropdown.empty();
        }
    });

    // Set search input value on click of result item
    $(document).on("click", ".result Button", function(){
        $(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
       // $(this).parent(".result").empty();
    });
});
</script>
```

[i need the two name to get inside of textbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlYpD.png)

Comment: Replace: `$(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());` with `var element = $(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]'); var currentVal = element.val(); element.val(currentVal + " " + $(this).text());`

Comment: Explanation: You need to get the current value first. Then append the new value to the current value and finally set the result as the new value. Since setting the value replaces the current value.

Comment: partially working ,  it's adding the letter 'j' i typed before to the search

Comment: let me make it more clear : i type letters in search box and instantly it returns back ; when i type "j" it returns as showen in the image i provided. the solution you provided did good but the letter j still concatenated with the other words

Answer (score 0):

Are the results of the operator clicks to be placed into
a single line (input) element or a multi-line (textarea) element?

First guess based upon code given would be
        var resultDropdown += $(this).siblings(".result");

BTW, welcome to the forums.

Comment: the result will take the place of the search textbox